# Why IGB driver stuck on Ubuntu18

Tags: drivers

```
Feb  6 06:10:17 server3 kernel: [2846318.756928] ata9: SATA link down (SStatus 0 SControl 300)
Feb  6 06:10:17 server3 kernel: [2846319.496917] igb 0000:05:00.0 enp5s0: PCIe link lost
Feb  6 06:10:17 server3 kernel: [2846319.498118] ------------[ cut here ]------------
Feb  6 06:10:17 server3 kernel: [2846319.498121] igb: Failed to read reg 0xc030!
Feb  6 06:10:17 server3 kernel: [2846319.498221] WARNING: CPU: 1 PID: 1897 at drivers/net/ethernet/intel/igb/igb_main.c:747 igb_rd32.cold+0x3a/0x46 [igb]
Feb  6 06:10:17 server3 kernel: [2846319.498223] Modules linked in: cpuid ipmi_ssif intel_rapl_msr intel_rapl_common sb_edac x86_pkg_temp_thermal intel_powerclamp core$
Feb  6 06:10:17 server3 kernel: [2846319.498322] CPU: 1 PID: 1897 Comm: kworker/1:1 Tainted: G        W         5.10.1-051001-generic #202012142031
Feb  6 06:10:17 server3 kernel: [2846319.498325] Hardware name: ASUSTeK COMPUTER INC. TS500-E8-PS4 V2/Z10PA-D8 Series, BIOS 3208 12/09/2016
Feb  6 06:10:17 server3 kernel: [2846319.498336] Workqueue: events igb_watchdog_task [igb]
Feb  6 06:10:17 server3 kernel: [2846319.498350] RIP: 0010:igb_rd32.cold+0x3a/0x46 [igb]
Feb  6 06:10:17 server3 kernel: [2846319.498356] Code: c7 c6 1c 04 3b c0 e8 22 5f e5 ca 48 8b bb 30 ff ff ff e8 5f d7 88 ca 84 c0 74 16 44 89 ee 48 c7 c7 78 10 3b c0 e$
Feb  6 06:10:17 server3 kernel: [2846319.498358] RSP: 0018:ffff9f9b49743dd0 EFLAGS: 00010286
Feb  6 06:10:17 server3 kernel: [2846319.498362] RAX: 0000000000000000 RBX: ffff8f5089b34ed0 RCX: ffff8f51f7c58a48
Feb  6 06:10:17 server3 kernel: [2846319.498364] RDX: 00000000ffffffd8 RSI: 0000000000000027 RDI: ffff8f51f7c58a40
Feb  6 06:10:17 server3 kernel: [2846319.498366] RBP: ffff9f9b49743de8 R08: 0000000000000000 R09: ffff9f9b49743bb0
Feb  6 06:10:17 server3 kernel: [2846319.498368] R10: ffff9f9b49743ba8 R11: ffffffff8c32a6e8 R12: 00000000ffffffff
Feb  6 06:10:17 server3 kernel: [2846319.498370] R13: 000000000000c030 R14: 0000000000000000 R15: ffff8f5089ac1b40
Feb  6 06:10:17 server3 kernel: [2846319.498373] FS:  0000000000000000(0000) GS:ffff8f51f7c40000(0000) knlGS:0000000000000000
Feb  6 06:10:17 server3 kernel: [2846319.498375] CS:  0010 DS: 0000 ES: 0000 CR0: 0000000080050033
Feb  6 06:10:17 server3 kernel: [2846319.498377] CR2: 0000557ec1149d60 CR3: 000000035f810005 CR4: 00000000003706e0
Feb  6 06:10:17 server3 kernel: [2846319.498379] DR0: 0000000000000000 DR1: 0000000000000000 DR2: 0000000000000000
```

my server stuck on error.. network has disconnected, help me please

Comment: Ubuntu 18?    Ubuntu desktop and server releases have a *yy.mm* format, and whilst specialist *snap* based releases like Ubuntu Core 18 for IoT appliances do use a *yy* format there are none titled just Ubuntu 18.  Please clarify your release as there is no Ubuntu 18.  (Server could mean the main Ubuntu 18.04 LTS Server release, or the specialist Ubuntu Core 18 which is intended for headless server systems, esp. in the cloud)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

2 possible causes:

1. hardware error regarding power supply that can come from an older or bugged BIOS. If it is use `pcie_port_pm=off` as a boot parameter and it should circumvent it (but not fix it). If that works add it to the line `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT` (`sudo gedit /etc/default/grub`). It can have side effects so test it out from grub command 1st. [More on how to do this](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/KernelBootParameters).
2. driver error. If this is the cause reloading it should work

   ```
   modprobe -r igb
   sleep 1
   modprobe igb
   sleep 1
   systemctl restart network
   ```

   In that case you might want to add these lines somewhere in the boot process.

Comment: @Rinzwind can you explain why you think this has somthing to do with power supply? Iam currently facing this issue aswell.

Comment: Because of the `igb: Failed to read reg 0xc030` in the error message. It is a hex code that points to messages online where a pci card (often a NIC) does not get (enough) power. But it could then also be a faulty driver for that card (though less likely). If the prm in the answer works: `pcie_port_pm=` sets power management of conventional PCI.

Comment: @Rinzwind thanks! I cant find a source that says this, can you post an example post where it is referenced? I wanna make an online-guide on howto fix this. Is there a way to reproduce the error, I fixed it by rebooting multiple times. And cant try the fixes because the error is currently not there.